# Can I install Ubuntu on my phone (Sony Ericsson w8)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can I install Ubuntu operating system on my phone (Sony Ericsson w8)? How to install? Does it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Sony Xperia S and Sony Xperia T are working at the moment, so if you want to install Ubuntu you'll have to port it yourself, or have it ported

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices are the devices that are currently supported
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting if you want to try to port it to your phone.

You also could request the port at xda-developers

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, the Sony Ericsson W8 is not on the list https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices and the hardware isn't capable of running Ubuntu Touch developer preview.